# Use of if statement in for loop in this code

Tags: matlab

What does the statement `for if=ilow:ihigh`  mean in this program?

```
function [d]=for_taup(m,dt,h,q,N,flow,fhigh);

nt= max(size(m));
nh = max(size(h));
M = fft(m,[],1);
D = zeros(nt,nh);
i = sqrt(-1);
ilow = floor(flow*dt*nt)+1; if ilow<1; ilow=1;end;
ihigh = floor(fhigh*dt*nt)+1;
if ihigh>floor(nt/2)+1; ihigh=floor(nt/2)+1;end
for if=ilow:ihigh
f = 2.*pi*(if-1)/nt/dt;
L = exp(i*f*(h.^N)’*q);
x = M(if,:)’;
y = L * x;
D(if,:) = y’;
D(nt+2-if,:) = conj(y)’;
end
D(nt/2+1,:) = zeros(1,nh);
d = real(ifft(D,[],1));
return;
```

Comment: I'm surprised that code even runs.  `if` is a reserved keyword.  Whoever wrote that program needs to be shot (no offence).

Comment: @rayryeng LOL yeah.. also `if` is used as condition just above the code where `if` is overwritten as a variable. It wouldn't have run if it was used below that :D

Comment: @rayryeng It doesn't run, for exactly the reason you'd expect `if ` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`if` is used as a variable name. I am surprised that this does not raise a syntax error: most languages would forbid the use of "reserved" keywords. Maybe it would be a good idea to replace `if` with a different name in order to clarify your code and avoid confusion.

Comment: It does raise a syntax error, because `if` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

As far as MATLAB is concerned, this code doesn't really mean anything, because it's just a syntax error. `if` is reserved keyword, and you can't create a variable called `if`. As such, it just instantly errors and won't run.

You should probably replace all occurrences of the variable `if` (although not the keyword `if` in lines 8 and 10) with some other variable name. Avoid `i`, since you're using that as the imaginary unit.